# New column of dates grouped

Tags: r

I have dates in my data frame and I want to create a new variables where I uses the date to group them into time periods. The time periods would be

1980-1989
1990-1999
2000-2012

They are of class date

```
date_of_delivery
1984-02-03
1997-08-01
2007-04-25
1999-04-05
```

The new column would look like

```
date_of_delivery  dod_group
1984-02-03        1980-1989
1997-08-01        1990-1999
2007-04-25        2000-2012
1999-04-05        1990-1999
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cut`:

```r
cutoffs <- setNames(as.Date(c("1980-01-01", "1990-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2013-01-01")), c("1980-1989", "1990-1999", "2000-2012", "Future"))
cutoffs
#    1980-1989    1990-1999    2000-2012       Future 
# "1980-01-01" "1990-01-01" "2000-01-01" "2013-01-01" 
cut(dat$date_of_delivery, cutoffs, labels = names(cutoffs)[-length(cutoffs)])
# [1] 1980-1989 1990-1999 2000-2012 1990-1999
# Levels: 1980-1989 1990-1999 2000-2012
```

There are `factor`s. If you want them as strings/`character`, then

```r
as.character(cut(dat$date_of_delivery, cutoffs, labels = names(cutoffs)[-length(cutoffs)]))
# [1] "1980-1989" "1990-1999" "2000-2012" "1990-1999"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the Date method of `cut` from base R.

```
data$dod_group <- cut(as.Date(c("1980-01-01",data$date_of_delivery),
                              "%Y-%m-%d"),
                      breaks = "10 years")[-1]
data
#  date_of_delivery  dod_group
#1       1984-02-03 1980-01-01
#2       1997-08-01 1990-01-01
#3       2007-04-25 2000-01-01
#4       1999-04-05 1990-01-01
```

I added `"1980-01-01"` to get the groups to start at that date, and the `breaks = "10 years"` argument to get the breaks to be decades. Finally, I subsetted the resulting break vector with `[-1]` to get rid of the initial date.

Sample data:

```
data <- structure(list(date_of_delivery = c("1984-02-03", "1997-08-01", 
"2007-04-25", "1999-04-05")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```